# I'm having log in issues using bcrypt

Tags: security, encryption, hash, passwords, bcrypt

I apologize in advance if this is a stupid question or if it's in the wrong place. This is my first time here. I've been stuck on this all day and I can't seem to fix the problem. I've never used bcrypt before but I followed several online tutorials and I was able to create a functioning sign up page. 
Here's the encryption code:

```
$password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT)."\n";
```

The sign up page works perfectly and the passwords are encrypted in the database. From my understanding, in the sign in page what happens is that we use a Select statement to get the hashed password for the username/email the user enters and then we use password_verify. So here's my code:

```
$email = $_POST['user_email'];
$password = $_POST['user_password'];


$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT Password FROM user WHERE Email= :email");
$stmt->execute(array(':email' => $email));
$hash = $stmt->fetchColumn(0);

if (password_verify($password, $hash)) {
    echo 'Password is valid!';
} else {
    echo 'Invalid password.';
}
```

For some reason, it still keeps saying "Invalid Password". I tried printing the hash that the select statement returns to make sure it is the one in the DB and it is. I also tried copying the hash and placing it in password_verify to try and find out what the problem is but it still won't work. Do you have any ideas for me?

Thanks everyone :o)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you generate the hash, don't append a newline to it with `."\n"` I'm pretty sure you're saving it to the database with that. It'll appear fine when printed but never verify.

---

#### Working:

```
$password = 'test';
$hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

if (password_verify($password, $hash)) {
    echo 'Password is valid!';
} else {
    echo 'Invalid password.';
}
```

#### Output:

```
Password is valid!
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Turns out there was another silly mistake as well. In my user table, I had assigned the format of the password field to VARCHAR with a limit of 20. So the hash wouldn't be saved entirely. So it never matched. Now it works, and I'm so happy :)